# Is it possible to restore Perforce changelist history having only versioned files without metadata?

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to restore Perforce changelist history having only versioned files without metadata? By "versioned files" I mean the versioned files that are usually located in directories under the root directory, for example in C:\ProgFiles\Perforce\Server\depot.
By metadata I mean changelists, opened files, labels. Metadata are stored in the Perforce database: db.* files. Admin says all metadata and journal are demaged and lost and it's not possible to restore depot. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the metadata and journal are damaged, and you don't have checkpoints, then it's likely you're going to lose the history. However, I would contact Perforce support, as they may be able to salvage some of the information.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I started this project only week ago, there are(were) 30-40 commits in it and It's not worth to disturb "heavy metal".